# Allowing (or circumventing) parallel write access to a file

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm calling a Windows executable from multiple parallel R processes (via a `system` call within `parSapply`). This .exe (let's call it `my.exe`) is passed a filename as an argument, and processes this file (details are probably irrelevant). Unfortunately, `my.exe` creates a log file (in the same directory as `my.exe`) that it writes to while it runs, and, since the log file's name is fixed, subsequent R processes calling `my.exe` results in my.exe` throwing the error:

```
Cannot create result file "log.res". 
Do you have write access in the current directory?
```

I've managed to work around this by creating multiple copies of the `my.exe` (as many as the number of cores in my `cluster`, i.e. 7). I can then ensure that each is only in use by a single R process at any one time, by passing to the cores a vector of 7 paths to .bat files, each of which repeatedly calls a given copy of `my.exe`.

Is there a more elegant way to deal with this issue, perhaps by having the processes create virtual instances of `my.exe` automagically? I don't require the log files.

**Since this is an error thrown by the program and not by R, I suspect there might be no way to permit concurrent write access to the log file from the R side of things.**

Ideally, I want to be doing something like this:

```
ff <- c('a', 'long', 'vector', 'of', 'file', 'paths') # abbreviated
parSapply(cl, ff, function(f) system(sprintf("my.exe %s", f)))
```

but instead I've resorted to doing (more or less) this (after copying `my.exe` to `c:/1/`, `c:/2/`, `c:/3/`, through `c:/7/`):

```
cat(paste('CALL C:/1/my.exe',  ff[1:10], '/RUN=YES'), file='run1.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/2/my.exe', ff[11:20], '/RUN=YES'), file='run2.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/3/my.exe', ff[21:30], '/RUN=YES'), file='run3.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/4/my.exe', ff[31:40], '/RUN=YES'), file='run4.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/5/my.exe', ff[41:50], '/RUN=YES'), file='run5.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/6/my.exe', ff[51:60], '/RUN=YES'), file='run6.bat', sep='\n')
cat(paste('CALL C:/7/my.exe', ff[61:70], '/RUN=YES'), file='run7.bat', sep='\n')
parSapply(cl, c('run1.bat', 'run2.bat', 'run3.bat', 'run4.bat',
                'run5.bat', 'run6.bat', 'run7.bat'), system)
```

(Above, instead of letting `parSapply` assign the 70 elements of `ff` to the various processes, I manually split them when creating the batch files, and then run the batch files in parallel.)

Comment: So changing the name of the executable changes the name of the log file? Is the name of the log file determined by the name of the executable? And where is the log file created? The current working directory?

Comment: @SteveWeston The name of the log file is constant, irrespective of the path to `my.exe`, but is created alongside `my.exe`, so copying `my.exe` to different directories and calling these from the various R processes prevents them from all accessing the same log. I've made some corrections to the post to clarify this (and to fix some inaccuracies in the code block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your basic strategy is the only known solution to the problem, but I think it can be done more elegantly. For instance, you could avoid creating .BAT files by having each worker execute a different command line based on a worker ID. The worker ID could be assigned using:

```
# Assign worker ID's to each of the cluster workers
setid <- function(id) assign(".Worker.id", id, pos=globalenv())
clusterApply(cl, seq_along(cl), setid)
```

Also, you may want to automate the creation of the directories that contain "my.exe". I also prefer to use a symlink rather than a copy of the executable:

```
# Create directories containing a symlink to the real executable
exepath <- "C:/bin/my.exe"  # Path to the real executable
pdir <- getwd()  # Parent of the new executable directories
myexe <- file.path(pdir, sprintf("work_%d", seq_along(cl)), "my.exe")
for (x in myexe) {
  dir.create(dirname(x), showWarnings=FALSE)
  if (file.exists(x)) 
    unlink(x)
  file.symlink(exepath, x)
}
```

If symlinks don't fool "my.exe" into creating the log file in the desired directory, you could try using "file.copy" instead of "file.symlink".

Now you can run your parallel job using:

```
# Each worker executes a different symlink to the real executable
worker.fun <- function(f, myexe) {
  system(sprintf("%s %s /RUN=YES", myexe[.Worker.id], f))
}
ff <- c('a', 'long', 'vector', 'of', 'file', 'paths')
parSapply(cl, ff, worker.fun, myexe)
```

You could also delete the directories that were created, but they don't use much space since symlinks are used, so it might be better to keep them, especially during debugging/testing.

Comment: Great ideas, Steve. I have been automating the creation of duplicate executables, but using symlinks is sensible. Using worker IDs also looks like it'll simplify things. Cheers!